# Why in Objective-C I can't invoke method b() in method a(), where a and b are in one interface

Tags: objective-c

Actually I build and compile my project with no problem one month age, but today I open my project and go ahead modifying something, I find there is a problem and I don't know why!

It looks like this.

I have a class(viewController.h/viewController.m)

in viewController.h, I declare two methods

```
-(void) a;

-(void) b;
```

in viewController.m, I implement them

```
-(void) a
{... b()\\invoke method b; ...}

-(void) b
{...\\do something}
```

but when I build the project, errors occur:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_b", referenced from:
>         -[ViewController a] in ViewController.o
>        (maybe you meant: dyld_stub_binding_helper) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How can I fix it?

Comment: Need more code to tell whats going on, sounds like you could be calling something that's perhaps unallocated?

Set breakpoints and figure out which line it's crashing on.

Comment: Read [“Working with Objects” in Apple's *Programming with Objective-C* guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW1).  You might want to read the rest of the guide too.

Comment: Instead of getting mad, find a good tutorial on the Objective-C programming language. Learn the basics of the language like how to make method calls.

Comment: thanks guys, if i have enough time, I'll read the tutorial you suggested

Comment: @ToniYU It takes less time to do it right the first time. The time it takes to read the tutorial will save you way more time in wasted coding issues like this one. Don't skimp on the learning. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use C functions:

viewController.h:

```
void a();
void b();
```

viewController.m:

```
void a() {
    b();
}
void b() {
    // do something
}
```

or, you can use Objective-C methods:

viewController.h:

```
- (void)a;
- (void)b;
```

viewController.m:

```
- (void)a {
    [self b];
}
- (void)b {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really should read a tutorial to learn the very basic

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to call method `b` as if it was a C function, instead of an Objective-C method.  The correct way is:

```
- (void)a
{
    [self b];    // Call method b
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I have little knowledge with objc developing. It's the first time using it. I'll read more tutorials and learn the very basic.